# I created a Swift Package and would like to include a function that returns both the name and the version of the package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I have a main app that will access multiple (self-created) Swift Packages. For a better user and tester experience I'd like to have a page that displays all Swift Package names and their respective version, however, these should be accessed programmatically and not in a hard-coded manner.
Since SPs only have their `Package.swift` file, which so far I couldn't access (programmatically) from within the SP, I'm running out of ideas how to approach this issue. Any suggestions?

In previous approaches, where frameworks were added directly into the project, I could simply get these values the following way:

```swift
if let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "<framework_bundle_id>") {
   if let res = bundle.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") {
      return res
   }
}
```

For Swift Packages I still need a new solution.